# Can't figure out "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting the error "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects" when i try running this for some reason

I'm following a tutorial on YouTube and it seems to work for them

```py
name = "Tan"
age = 20
print("Hello my name is " + name + " and i am " + age + " years old")
age = 17
name = "Taq"
print("Hello my name is " + name + " and i am " + age + " years old")
```

The age is meant to be assigned as 20 and then as 17 but it just gives an error.

Comment: You can't add an int to a string. Make the int a string first, then add it

Comment: Also, if you're learning Python right now, stop learning Python 2.7 and learn Python 3. Python 2.7 will [stop being officially supported](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#id2) next year.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your integers to strings before you can concatenate them:

```py
a = 'I can eat '
b = 5
c = ' biscuits.'
print(a + str(b) + c)
```

Or you could use string formatting to approach this problem:

```py
a = 5
print('I can eat {} biscuits.'.format(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, do it like this:
`print("Hello my name is " + name + " and i am " + str(age) + " years old")`
You need to cast the age into a **string** before you concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the integer age to string before concatenating
`... + str(age)+...`